Valid and logically valid formula in first-order logic?
I am a bit confused about what "valid" and "logically valid" mean. Are they synonymous? When examples of logically valid formulas are presented they are basically tautologies e.g. $\forall x: (x=x)$, $R(x_1,c) \rightarrow \exists x_2 R(x_1,x_2)$, etc. They are indeed true for all interpretations and all value assignments, therefore matching the definition of logically valid.
Then there are soundness and completeness theorems which state that:

Soundness: $\Gamma \vdash \phi \rightarrow \Gamma \vDash \phi$ -- if provable, then valid.
Completeness: $\Gamma \vDash \phi \rightarrow \Gamma \vdash \phi$ -- if valid, then provable.

So for example, if we have a group theory consisting of axioms G1-G3 and there is a theorem $\phi$ that follows from the axioms, then the theorem is considered valid? It seems like valid in this case is some sort of short way of saying that $G1 \land G2 \land G3 \rightarrow \phi$ is logically valid. Is this correct?

"confused about what "valid" and "logically valid" mean. Are they synonymous?" Yes, thet are.

@MauroALLEGRANZA so if I understood correctly, the definition of completeness could be restated as: if $\bigwedge \Gamma \rightarrow \phi$ is logically valid, then provable?

@MauroALLEGRANZA what if T is finite? Just trying to understand why T being infinite is a problem to what I said.

$\Gamma \vDash \phi$ means that $\phi$ is true whenever all statements in $\Gamma$ are true.  We can say that $\Gamma$ implies (or better put: logically implies) $\phi$, or that $\phi$ logically follows from $\Gamma$. We can also say that $\Gamma$ validly implies $\phi$, or that $\phi$ validly follows from $\Gamma$. And if we treat the statements of $\Gamma$ as the premises of an argument, whose conclusion is $\phi$, then we can say that that argument is (logically) valid.
If $\Gamma$ is a single statement $\psi$, we will sometimes use $\Rightarrow$. That is: $\psi \Rightarrow \phi$ means that statement $\psi$ logically implies $\phi$ . or that $\phi$ is logicialy implied by $\psi$ .. or that $\phi$ validly follows from $\psi$.
But note, we don't say that $\phi$ by itself is valid... unless $\Gamma$ happens to be an empty set of statements. In such a case, we sometimes write $\vDash \phi$.  A statement that is always true 'by itself' is a logical necessity, or valid statement. You could say it is a tautology .. though 'tautology' is (for some reason unclear to me) often reserved for the domain of propositional logic.
Finally, yes, there is a connection between logical implication (validity) and the necessary truth of a single conditional. For example, we have that $\psi \Rightarrow \phi$ if and only if $\psi \to \phi$ is a logical necessity, i.e. if and only if $\psi \to \phi$ is a (logically) valid statement.
When $\Gamma$ is a set of statement, you could try to do something similar and conjunct all the statements of $\Gamma$ to use as the antecedent of a conditional, but as Mauro points out, that only works when $\Gamma$ is finite, because (at least in classical formal logic) the formal language is such that it only allows for finitely long statements.  But sure, if you are dealing with just 3 axioms $G1, G2, G3$, then you can either say that $\phi$ validly follows from those 3 axioms (and thus is a theorem 'of' those axioms), or you could say that $(G1 \land G2 \land G3) \to \phi$ is a logically valid statement. Frankly, I would just stick with the former, because it is simpler, and also because it avoids this whole potential finite/infinite thing.

@ryang Thanks for pointing out the typos!  As far as that closed question goes ... yeah, none of them are super clear answers to the question. Only the second one comes somewhat close: the accepted answer to that one at least shows that depending on the assumptions you are making you can show 1+1=2 or 1+1 != 2, so from that it should become clear that 1+1=2 is not a logical truth, but I think my Answer makes that much more directly and explicitly clear.

Regarding "valid" and "logically valid" respective meanings: yes, they are synonymous.
Regarding the example with group theory, we say that the theorem follows from or is a logical consequnece of the axioms.
And yes, this means that the formula $G_1 ∧ G_2 ∧ G_3 \to \phi$ is logically valid; see the Deduction theorem.
The general form of the Completeness theorem is:

We say that a sentence $\phi$ is a syntactic consequence of a theory $\Gamma$, denoted $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, if $\phi$ is provable from $\Gamma$ in the deductive system. We say that $\phi$ is a semantic consequence of $\Gamma$, denoted $\Gamma \vDash \phi$, if $\phi$ holds in every model of $\Gamma$. Since the converse (Soundness) also holds, it follows that $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, iff $\Gamma \vDash \phi$, and thus that syntactic and semantic consequence are equivalent for first-order logic.

Regarding $\bigwedge \Gamma \to \phi$, we have have to consider that the set of axioms $\Gamma$ can be infinite while in standard predicate logic a formula is a finite string: thus, an infinite conjunction is not syntactically allowed.

$\Gamma\vdash\phi$ means set $\Gamma$ syntactically entails $\phi$ by some proof system.  This is called valid, or syntactically valid, when a rigorous proof can be composed correctly applying the axioms and inference rules of the system. This is also called provable.
$\Gamma\models\phi$ means set $\Gamma$ semantically entails $\phi$. That is called valid, or semantically valid, when $\phi$ is valued as true in every interpretation that values all propositions in $\Gamma$ as true. This is sometimes called logically valid.
Then the soundness and completeness are defined as:

Soundness: $\Gamma\vdash\phi\implies\Gamma\models\phi$

if the syntax is valid, then the semantics will be valid. (if provable then logically valid).
A proof system is sound when this holds for every $\Gamma\cap\{\phi\}$ containing well-formed-formulae.


Completeness: $\Gamma\vDash\phi\implies\Gamma\vdash\phi$

if the semantics are valid, then the syntax will be valid. (if logically valid, then provable)
A proof system is complete when this holds for every for every $\Gamma\cap\{\phi\}$ containing well-formed-formulae.



